# Mage_Core_Model_App' not found magento XAMPP

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, fatal-error

I am setting up magento on my mac in XAMPP server but when I hit the url:

http://localhost/magento/

I get a error message :

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_App' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php on line 636

does any one know what exactly issue?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution the issue was only about permissions in folder app/etc,var,media

cd /path_to_magento_folder/magento
chmod -R 777 app/etc
chmod -R 777 var
chmod -R 777 media

finally run successfully.